# Standard library in ABAP

Tags: abap, standard-library

Is there something similar to a standard library for modern ABAP (maybe even OO-Abap)? For example a curated list of objects that address some of the most common programming tasks like

- high-level data structures (not just plain internal tables)
- working with file paths and directories
- working with files (reading, saving, ...)
- working with different file types (text, csv, xml, ...)
- regular expressions
- working with the environment (client, application server)
- ...

My current workflow is to stumble upon a problem like getting the extension of a file from a filename (or something fairly similar and easy). Then I have three options:

1. Dig through a ton of (mostly old and lacking) posts on SDN until i maybe find a pointer to solve the problem
2. Hack away and create a one-off solution to the problem
3. Take my time and implement a good and well documented solution

Many times I feel a bit lost. A lot of the available information is old, bad or both. Is there a more structured approach to tackle the problem of finding a suitable abstraction in the ABAP-world?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you know about [ABAP keywords](http://help-legacy.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abenabap_shortref.htm)? Why don't split the path at dots and read the last element?

Comment: Unfortunately no. ABAP has no library concept period, so there can't really be a standard library. There are a bunch of utility function modules and classes that are packaged with Netweaver, but the ones that are available will depend on the Netweaver version you are on. A library/package concept is something that ABAP desperately needs but that SAP has failed to provide. ABAPGit and accompanying projects are about as close as you can get right now (https://github.com/larshp/abapGit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question no, unlike C, C#, Java, there is no need to include a library since all the functions are always available to you, so in that regards it might be simpler. What you are asking though is a great question, I am sure you probably see tons of queries in SDN for "Is there a Function module for?" etc.

There isn't an easy answer but In SAP ABAP I think the easiest way might be to find this is by looking at packages. Similar to a library by looking at a package for the type of function your looking for might get you there. For example if I am looking for handling files I might look for the control framework package and there I can see all the available functions/classes/methods/BAPIs etc. that are related to front end controls/file handling etc. and might be able to find what I am looking for. Note its not perfect as the way packages are used has changed from time to time so its actually better for finding functions related to for example purchasing or sales etc. but its one way that we use.

Like other languages in that we still need to know what library to link in to get the function you need, in ABAP you just have to find the related package. Hope it helps a little, I know its not perfect. [Example package for front end controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE1xs.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! One question remains though - SAP Systems are huge and there are a lot of packages ... how do you determine if an abstraction is obsolet?

Comment: Another good question, sadly the only way to know when they are obsolete is by looking closely at the code of a specific function, method etc. , SAP is not consistent in its way of handling this so sometimes you see it in the attributes description, it will say things like - "Obsolete do not use" or other time you will see it in the documentation header in their code it will say things like, "Deprecated use new method........." . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For working with the environment:

If you have access to SAP there is a transaction code called BAPI

Here you could find a hierarchical list of all the main objects in SAP (i.e. Material, Purchase Order, etc)

In this list you could find documentation, the function modules used for the object (i.e. créate/get detail/update etc)

And digging into the function modules could take a look to the structures, receiving parameters, etc

The other questions are a little bit complex, I am not aware of any comprehensive list but digging into SCN usually is easy to find a solution for the most common things like handling files, etc

In the particular case of regular expressions, SAP native language, ABAP, has keywords for handling them, but you also have a class in SAP called CL_JAVA_SCRIPT which you could use for doing thigs in "JavaScript way"

For example I used this class in the past to evaluate a simple formula provided in a string (i.e 3 + 2 * 5 )

This is an operation really complex to do in ABAP but easy to do in JS.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

SAP Reuse Library (SE83) is the most close thing to what you are looking for. It provides common development tasks grouped in hierarchy (UI controls, standard dialogs, confirmation prompts) and contains code snippets for each with commonly used classes/modules:

[image]

Though, it is incomplete and lacks many popular things.

Consider also DWDM, BIBS, LIBS transactions and other packages in [this link](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Examples+and+demos+by+SAP).